# Use Google Drive as a PDF file server for my Website

Tags: html, pdf

I am building a simple public website that will allow users to search and view various PDF files. I plan to store the PDF files on a public folder in my Google Drive. The link to my test folder is:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pBTWzuElA-gSLPvQAHlnonamfon6V1NW

In this folder there are 2 PDF files - File1.PDF and File2.PDF

I would like to be able to link to these from an HTML page but have no idea how to do it - I have searched this forum but with no luck so far - the closest I have found is how to download files from gdrive via a local program rather than a public website

Comment: Do you want to get the **pdf** links dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive has its own api that you could use [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
Hope this help